# 400 bad request google big query streaming

Tags: streaming, google-bigquery

I have a ASP.Net application in which I am trying to insert rows in google bigquery through streaming (tabledata.insertAll()). I am doing this by HTTP POST request and in the request body, i am supplying data with the following structure:

{
  "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
  "rows": [
    {
      "insertId": string,
      "json": {
        (key): (value)
      }
    }
  ]
}

When I am passing more than 100 rows (such as 101) in the request body, it gives me 400 bad request error. But when I pass 100 rows or less than 100, then it works fine with no errors.

Is there any limit of rows while using streaming?

Answer (score 2):

The tableData.insertAll() has a :

> - Maximum row size: 100 KB
> - Maximum data size of all rows, per insert: 1 MB
> - Maximum rows per second: 100 rows per second, per table, with       allowed and occasional bursts of up to 1,000 rows per second. If you
>     exceed 100 rows per second for an extended period of time, throttling 
>     might occur.

Visit https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery for the streaming quota policy.

Answer (score 1):

Update from https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery :

The following limits apply for streaming data into BigQuery.

- Maximum row size: 20 KB
- Maximum data size of all rows, per insert: 1
  MB
- Maximum rows per second: 10,000 rows per second, per table.
  Exceeding this amount will cause quota_exceeded errors. For
  additional support up to 100,000 rows per second, per table, please
  contact a sales representative.
- Maximum bytes per second: 10 MB per
  second, per table.
- Exceeding this amount will cause quota_exceeded
  errors.

I think you gonna stop to get this kinda of errors.